# Deleting a memory-mapped files in iOS - what's going on behind the scenes?

Tags: ios, nsdata, memory-mapped-files

I have a file which I memory-map with NSData. I then delete this file via an NSFileManager without any error, and proceed to check that the file is indeed not there (as far as NSFileManager and ls are concerned). However, I can still read data from the bytes pointer I got from NSData previously!

In the simulator, I sometimes get seemingly unrelated crashes. On the device, everything seems to work fine. I'm very curious to know what's going on, and what should I expect (what I expected in the past is to either get an error when trying to delete the file or a crash when I try to access it after it was deleted).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you didn't unmap the memory, then the mmap you made with the file pointer is keeping the file from getting deleted (even though you cannot see it). you should always unmap memory before deleting the referenced file.

[This relates to an old UNIX trick - open a file, once you have a file descriptor then unlink the file - you have a file you can do things with but no one can see, and if you crash the file completely goes away!]

Comment: Interesting. Is this documented somewhere? Also, will the OS prevent those bytes from being overwritten? So technically I could fill an entire storage device with ghost files, leaving no available memory, while the user will think the device has lots of free memory?

Comment: Well, those ghost files only live as long as your app is running. I use this technique all the time when I create files I want to disappear if the app crashes - temp files so to speak - instead of having to clear my internal directories when I launch. I found this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlink_(Unix) but you can find others googling for "unix trick unlink open file". All the info on how it works is documented, its just the technique isn't in any man page I know of.

Comment: This is documented in `man 2 unlink` on a Unix terminal near you :-) (At least it says that unlinking a file that is still open won't actually delete the file -- it doesn't explain what that's good for)